# How to build CGAL with tracing enabled (esp CGAL_NEF_TRACEN)

Tags: cmake, cgal

I am trying to debug an assertion failure exception I get with the CGAL library. CGAL has well placed debug and trace statements all over the library, which I can use to understand what's happening in my case. However despite many efforts I could not find the right compile time flags that will enables those debug and trace messages. I am especially interested in the trace messages printed with the `CGAL_NEF_TRACEN` macro. I have tried to compile with the cmake option `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`, but to no avail. I don't have much experience with cmake. Please let me know if you know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer on [cgal-discuss mailing list](https://lists-sop.inria.fr/sympa/arc/cgal-discuss/2011-05/msg00019.html). Compile a debug version and set the global variable `debugthread` to 0.